# Running Android Studio on Windows 10

Tags: android

I have a Dell Laptop that came with Windows 7 installed. I downloaded Android Studio 1.5 and installed it with the SDK's. I was able to run Android Studio and import a sample project and run it.

Then, I upgraded to Windows 10. I uninstalled Android Studio sensing that a compatibility issue would arise. I installed Android Studio 1.5 again and the required SDK's were downloaded and installed by the installer. The installer also opened Android Studio and allowed me to import the sample project.

I quit Android Studio and tried to run it again clicking on the Studio64 executable in one of the bin files. Windows 10 rejected Android Studio with the message, "This app can't run on your PC".

I don't understand why Windows 10 did nothing when Android Studio was run the first time by the installer but chose to block me when I tried to run it again.

Can someone explain and help me? Also, what is the solution?

Chandrasekharan K

Comment: have you tried you running the studio64.exe in  androidstudiodir/bin ?

Comment: In fact that was my mistake. Instead, I clicked on "Studio" and everything worked fine,

Answer (score 0):

I am facing same problem with android studio after upgrading windows 10..
first uninstall the studio and install again..

if you are installing studio in system drive.. don't do this..
choose different drive. and then set appropriate SDK path.

It will work for me.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem is to run the studio64.exe in androidstudiodir/bin ?